# How can I show post views counter?

Tags: custom-post-types

I want to show custom posts views counter. Also, I want to create a shortcode so that I can show it anywhere. Currently, It shows the custom posts list but with the "0" view. Can it be increased?

Here is the code so far:

```
function getPostViews($postID){
$author_id = ''; 
$author_posts = get_posts( array(
'author' => $author_id,
'post_type' => 'video'
) );

$counter = 0; 


foreach ( $author_posts as $post )
{
  $views = absint( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'views', true ) );
  $counter += $views;
  echo "<li style='color:#000;'>{$post->post_title} ({$views})</li>";
}
echo "</ul><hr /><p style='color:#000;'>Total Number of views: <strong> 
{$counter}</strong></p>";
}

add_shortcode('view','getPostViews');
```

Comment: Are you sure that the posts have values in the view meta_field? Did you check in the database?

Comment: I checked postmeta. There's a meta key called "viewed". Is it what you are asking?

Comment: How did you check? Did you open the database with phpMyAdmin for instance? Ok, you checked the meta_key. Is there a post where the VALUE for that meta_key is different from 0?

Comment: Yes, using phpmyadmin. All Values are set to 0.

Comment: So the problem isn't with getting and rendering the posts' views, but with counting them and updating the value in the database. You should look at your code that updates the post_meta `view`